# Dictionary comprehension destroys list of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to implement a ranked voting system in Python. I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

candidates = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Jim', 'Sarah', 'Paul', 'Jordan']

votes = np.matrix(
    '1 2 5 3 4 6;' \
    '1 2 3 4 5 6;' \
    '5 1 2 4 3 6;' \
    '6 2 1 3 4 5;' \
    '4 3 2 1 5 7'
    )

pairs = itertools.combinations(candidates, 2)  # All pairs of candidates

d = dict.fromkeys(pairs, 0)

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

The dictionary is:

```
d
=> {('Paul', 'Jordan'): 0, ('Alice', 'Sarah'): 0, ('Alice', 'Jim'): 0, ('Alice', 'Paul'): 0, ('Jim', 'Sarah'): 0, ('Sarah', 'Paul'): 0, ('Bob', 'Alice'): 0, ('Bob', 'Jordan'): 0, ('Jim', 'Jordan'): 0, ('Jim', 'Paul'): 0, ('Sarah', 'Jordan'): 0, ('Bob', 'Paul'): 0, ('Bob', 'Sarah'): 0, ('Bob', 'Jim'): 0, ('Alice', 'Jordan'): 0}
```

Which is what I want. But doing this seems to destroy the list of tuples, `pairs`.

If I take out the dictionary line, the code outputs:

```
('Bob', 'Alice')
('Bob', 'Jim')
('Bob', 'Sarah')
('Bob', 'Paul')
('Bob', 'Jordan')
('Alice', 'Jim')
('Alice', 'Sarah')
('Alice', 'Paul')
('Alice', 'Jordan')
('Jim', 'Sarah')
('Jim', 'Paul')
('Jim', 'Jordan')
('Sarah', 'Paul')
('Sarah', 'Jordan')
('Paul', 'Jordan')
```

With the dictionary line, nothing prints out.

I also tried a dictionary comprehension

```
d = {pair: 0 for pair in pairs}
```

And the same thing occurred. Why is the `pairs` list being destroyed?

Comment: `pairs` is an iterator not list of tuples.

Comment: Yah just recast it as a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you have with pairs is a generator not a typical list of tuples. passing a generator to `dict.fromkeys` is valid because it is iterable, however after iterating over pairs once, a `StopIteration` is called when you try to iterate again to print them

you could cast pairs to a list at creation by adding:

`pairs = list(itertools.combinations(candidates, 2))`

Answer (score 4):

`pairs` is a generator, and generators can be iterated over *only once*. So, `fromkeys` does that iteration, and therefore `pairs` is now exhausted and doesn't contain anything. To be precise, *generators* (as kindly pointed out by @chepner), don't actually contain all the data that you receive while iterating over them; they're generating it *on the fly*.

If you'd like to use `pairs` *one more time*, you could split it into two different generators with `itertools.tee`:

```
pairs1, pairs2 = itertools.tee(itertools.combinations(...))
```

Then you use one of them to create the dictionary and another one - to do the printing.

While you could simply convert `pairs` to a list, this approach may waste a lot of memory.